The need for @GeneratedValue in the entity class
So, @GeneratedValue describes the strategy for generating primary keys.. But then, how does it go together with the DB schemas that already have this set up in the sql query itself? Like PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT?
What if the strategy chosen conflicts with the one in already existing schema?
Can we omit this annotation in cases when we already have a set up DB?

For the case you are describing these are the correct annotations:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

GenerationType.IDENTITY indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.
You can't omit the annotation and it must be aligned with the database schema.
